# Django parsing a json request that has a dictionary result in error

Tags: python, ios, django, json, dictionary

I'm passing the following `NSMutableDictionary` as parameters of `AFNetworking` from iPhone application (IOS 6.1) to a Django server

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [parameters setObject:[self getProductDictionary] forKey:@"prodDic"];
    [parameters setObject:ApplicationDelegate.userUniqueId forKey:@"userID"];
     [manager POST:BaseURLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {...}

-(void) getProductDictionary
{
   NSMutableDictionary *products = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   [products setObject:@"aaa" forKey:@"prod1"];
   [products setObject:@"vvv" forKey:@"prod2"];
   [products setObject:@"bbb" forKey:@"prod3"];
}
```

in the server i have the following view:

```
import json
def foo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_id = request.POST['userID']
        products=json.loads(request.POST['prodDic'])

    return HttpResponse("Done")
```

the following line couses the error `products=json.loads(request.POST['prodDic'])` and the error is: `raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key)) MultiValueDictKeyError: "'prodDic'"`

for debug I removed the line and added this code:

```
 #for debug
 for key in request.POST:
    value = request.POST[key]
    print value
```

the key looks like this: **prodDic[prod1]**

how can I receive the dictionary into products so i can run over it like so:

```
for key in products:
   value = products[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

Request objects GET and POST can contain multiple values of same key. As some HTML form elements, notably , pass multiple values for the same key.

You are passing the request.POST object to JSON serializer which doesn't allow multiple keys with same name. So please inspect your request.POST data and see if you are getting multiple keys with same name or not. If yes then you have to process this data before passing to JSON load function.

I hope it will give you some pointers to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

This is what I finally found out... the problem started in objective c, passing the dictionary as is to AFNetworking caused the funny looking keys on the server side so

1. I've converted the NSDictionary to NSData
2. Converted the NSData to NSString
3. created a new dictionary with a "root" dummy key and the converted string as value

Here is my updated working code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parameters setObject:[self getProductDictionary] forKey:@"prodDic"];
[parameters setObject:ApplicationDelegate.userUniqueId forKey:@"userID"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[manager POST:BaseURLString parameters:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:jsonString, @"root",nil] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {...}
```

then in the server side:

```
import json
def foo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request_data=json.loads(request.POST['root'])
        products=request_data['prodDic']
        for key in products:
            value=products[key]
            #do my stuff
    return HttpResponse("Done")
```

hope this save someone time & agony :)